# Best way to store intent keys in my Android App

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I know I can simply copy and paste the string between activities to get the intent, but it may cause confusion if someone else get the project to continue it. I'd like to know how is the best way to store short keys to use through my application. The two possible ways I've tought are:

Creating an Enum with all my keys and every time I want to get one I simply use `myEnum.KeyOne.toString();`

And creating a resources xml file with the strings in it like `<string name="keyOne">KeyOne</string>` and calling using `activity.getString(R.string.keyOne)`.

Is there another better way? If not which o these is faster?

Comment: I personally like using a `Constants.java` file with static final variables in it. I'm not a huge fan of referencing variables in the `strings.xml` file and for whatever reason I've never liked using Enums. I really don't know if this is the best way or the fastest but it has worked well for me. I use it for bundle keys and endpoints, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also make package `constants` and there some `class`es how `GlobalConstants` or `SpecificConstants` with **static final String**s for intent keys.

Answer (score 0):

Using Enum as constant may expensive. You can easily create a class just store every constant value there..

```
public class Constants{
     public static final String KEY1 = "your_key1";
     public static final String KEY2 = "your_key2";
     public static final String KEY3 = "your_key3";
     ....
}
```